# DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer without SeekToCurrentErrorHandler

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a very simple use case. I have one Kafka Consumer and I want to move all invalid or partial messages to a dead letter queue. The example from the documentation uses `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` and to attach `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`. In my case, I don't want to retry these invalid messages and I have set the `maxFailures` to `1` (I have tried 0 as well with the same result). The problem here is that for some reason `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` seeks the partition every time I have an invalid message even that I just want to move it to DLT and this makes the whole process very slow. I'm not sure this is the right behavior from `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`, but still is there a better way to achieve my goal without `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`? Do I have to create custom `ErrorHandler`?

---

P.S.

The strange behavior of `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` is observed when there are more invalid messages then the consumer can buffer. If there are a few messages everything is fast, but when we have a big chunk of invalid messages it performs awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug - it is [fixed on master and 2.2.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/993). It will be in the 2.2.5 release due next week.

> The `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` and `DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor`
>   always retried at least one time, even if `maxAttempts` was 1.